# I am trying to run hyperledger fabric sample test network on windows 11

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

when executing "/network.sh up", I got this:
-bash: /network.sh: no such file or directory
how can I fix this?

I need to get the network up

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to run `/network.sh`. This will try to run a `network.sh` script in the root directory of your filesystem. More likely you meant to type `./network.sh`, which will run a `network.sh` script in your current working directory (`.` is interpreted by the shell as the current directory).

You give no details of how your environment is set up so make sure you are following the guidance on running in Windows provided by the Fabric documentation:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#windows

Essentially the recommendation is to run on Linux within a (Windows Subsystem for Linux) virtual machine. I personally run Docker within the Linux environment too, and don't use Docker Desktop for Windows. Either approach should work.